# Flash CS3 Deleting objects on stage

Tags: arrays, flash, object, flash-cs3

Ok so I have this minigame inside my main timeline. The minigame creates a bunch of objects dynamically inside an array using addChild(new a0), new a1, new a2 etc... Anyways at the end of the game, there's an option to either restart (resets scores and goes back to starting frame) or finished (goes back a few frames to the "main screen" which is on a different layer and back a few frames. If I choose either options, any of the objects that werent deleted from playing the game (getting a match) are left on the stage even when restarting or going back to the main frame. I've tried various methods of calling removeChild, setting arrays to empty and what not and I can't seem to figure out how to remove them. With the code that I will display here, I get this error:

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at mousiesDay_fla::MainTimeline/clearGame()[mousiesDay_fla.MainTimeline::frame258:11]
    at mousiesDay_fla::MainTimeline/tryAgain()[mousiesDay_fla.MainTimeline::frame258:29]

Here is the code

```
    stop();
scoreWindow.visible = false;
scoreWindowText.visible = false;
finBtn.visible = false;
tryBtn.visible = false;
finBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, finished);
tryBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tryAgain);

function clearGame() {
    for( var i:int = 0; i < numClips; i++ ) {
        removeChild( myClip[i] );

    }
    myClip.length = 0;
    scoreWindow.visible = false;
    scoreWindowText.visible = false;
    finBtn.visible = false;
    tryBtn.visible = false;
    finBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, finished);
    tryBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tryAgain);
}

function finished(evt:MouseEvent) {
    clearGame();
    gotoAndPlay(256);
}

function tryAgain(evt:MouseEvent) {
    clearGame();
    gotoAndPlay(257);
}

backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBack);

function goBack(evt:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndPlay(256);
}

import flash.utils.*;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timedFunction);
myTimer.start();

function timedFunction(eventArgs:TimerEvent) {
        var tc:int= 31 - myTimer.currentCount;
        pTime.text = tc.toString();
        if (myTimer.currentCount > 30) {
            for (var k:Number = 0; k < numClips; k++) {
                myClip[k].removeEventListener("mouseDown", pieceMove);
                myClip[k].removeEventListener("mouseUp", pieceMove);
            }
            myTimer.reset();
            myTimer.stop();
            scoreWindow.visible = true;
            scoreWindowText.visible = true;
            addChild(scoreWindow);
            addChild(scoreWindowText);
            scoreWindowText.text = "Congratulations. You got " + upgameScore + " / 10. \nClick FINISHED to go back or TRY AGAIN to restart.";
            finBtn.visible = true;
            finBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, finished);
            addChild(finBtn);
            tryBtn.visible = true;
            tryBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tryAgain);
            addChild(tryBtn);
        }
    }

var mySound:Sound = new correctSound(); 

upgameScore = 0;

var numClips:Number = 7;

var myClip = new Array(numClips);

myClip[0] = addChild(new a0());
myClip[1] = addChild(new a1());
myClip[2] = addChild(new a2());
myClip[3] = addChild(new a3());
myClip[4] = addChild(new a4());
myClip[5] = addChild(new a5());
myClip[6] = addChild(new a6());
//myClip[7] = addChild(new a7());
//myClip[8] = addChild(new a8());
//myClip[9] = addChild(new a9());

myClip[0].name = "piece0";
myClip[1].name = "piece1";
myClip[2].name = "piece2";
myClip[3].name = "piece3";
myClip[4].name = "piece4";
myClip[5].name = "piece5";
myClip[6].name = "piece6";
//myClip[7].name = "piece7";
//myClip[8].name = "piece8";
//myClip[9].name = "piece9";

var nph = new Array(numClips);

nph[0] = nph0_mc;
nph[1] = nph1_mc;
nph[2] = nph2_mc;
nph[3] = nph3_mc;
nph[4] = nph4_mc;
nph[5] = nph5_mc;
nph[6] = nph6_mc;
//nph[7] = nph7_mc;
//nph[8] = nph8_mc;
//nph[9] = nph9_mc;

var tpg = new Array(numClips);

tpg[0] = tpg0_mc;
tpg[1] = tpg1_mc;
tpg[2] = tpg2_mc;
tpg[3] = tpg3_mc;
tpg[4] = tpg4_mc;
tpg[5] = tpg5_mc;
tpg[6] = tpg6_mc;
//tpg[7] = tpg7_mc;
//tpg[8] = tpg8_mc;
//tpg[9] = tpg9_mc;

var x0 = myClip[0].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y0 = myClip[0].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x1 = myClip[1].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y1 = myClip[1].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x2 = myClip[2].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y2 = myClip[2].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x3 = myClip[3].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y3 = myClip[3].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x4 = myClip[4].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y4 = myClip[4].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x5 = myClip[5].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y5 = myClip[5].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x6 = myClip[6].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y6 = myClip[6].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
/*var x7 = myClip[7].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y7 = myClip[7].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x8 = myClip[8].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y8 = myClip[8].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
var x9 = myClip[9].x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
var y9 = myClip[9].y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;*/

var j:Number;

for (var k:Number = 0; k < numClips; k++) {
    myClip[k].addEventListener("mouseDown", pieceMove);
    myClip[k].addEventListener("mouseUp", pieceMove);
}

function pieceMove(evt:Event):void {
    if (evt.type == "mouseDown") {
        //mySound.play();
        evt.target.startDrag();
    }
    else if (evt.type == "mouseUp") {
        //mySound.play();
        evt.target.stopDrag();

for (j = 0; j < numClips; j++) {
    if (evt.target.name == "piece" + j && 
        evt.target.hitTestObject(nph[j]) == true) {
            removeChild(myClip[j]);
            nph[j].alpha = 0;
            tpg[j].alpha = 100;
            if (j == 2) {
                setChildIndex(tpg[j], 1);
            }

            upgameScore++;
        }
    else if (evt.target.name == "piece" + j) {
        evt.target.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+530-20))+20;//Math.random()*400+50;
        evt.target.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+380-20))+20;//Math.random()*50+50;
    }
}

scor.text = upgameScore.toString();

if (upgameScore == 10) {
    msgbox.text = "Congratulations !";
    for (var k:Number = 0; k < numClips; k++) {
        myClip[k].removeEventListener("mouseDown", pieceMove);
        myClip[k].removeEventListener("mouseUp", pieceMove);
    }
    myTimer.reset();
    myTimer.stop();
    scoreWindow.visible = true;
    scoreWindowText.visible = true;
    addChild(scoreWindow);
    addChild(scoreWindowText);
    scoreWindowText.text = "Congratulations. You got " + upgameScore + " / 10. \nClick FINISHED to go back or TRY AGAIN to restart.";

}

}
}
```

I should mention that if you look near the end of the code where I do the testHitObject and then call removeChild after that, THAT particular delete works and removes the object from the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one too. I should probably spend a bit more time before I post these.

As it turns out, when objects were being matched they were being removed as per the removeChild() function that was working. What I was doing then was iterating through the array and attempting to remove some objects that were already removed. So what i did was kept an array that matched the objects and when they were removed, changed a flag to 0. Then at the end, iterate through the new array and if there's a 1, remove the child object from the array with the same index. If there's a 0, ignore it. Now it works.